# Titanium - Perform Action when user clicks on Android Notification

Tags: javascript, notifications, titanium

I have code that displays an android notification and when someone clicks on that notification, the app comes to the foreground, if it was in the background before. But I want to additionally call a javascript function or run a javascript file after the app came to the forground. How can I do that?

**app.js**

```
if(!Ti.App.Properties.getBool("displayedNotifications")){
    var notifications = ["Apple","Orange","Banana"];

    for(var i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++){
        var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
            packageName:"com.company.notificationtest",
            className:"com.company.notificationtest.NotificationtestActivity",
            flags:Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED  | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        });
        intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.putExtra("name",notifications[i]);

        Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.notify(i, Titanium.Android.createNotification({
            contentTitle: notifications[i],
            contentText : notifications[i],
            contentIntent: Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({
                intent:intent,
                type : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY
            }),
            flags : Titanium.Android.ACTION_DEFAULT | Titanium.Android.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Titanium.Android.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS
        }));
    }

    Ti.App.Properties.setBool("displayedNotifications",true);
}
```

**tiapp.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <id>com.company.notificationtest</id>
    <name>NotificationTest</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <publisher>not specified</publisher>
    <url></url>
    <description>not specified</description>
    <copyright>not specified</copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>91e86075-373b-44e0-9416-66183390e8af</guid>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </android>    
    <modules>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="android">true</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>3.2.3.GA</sdk-version>
</ti:app>
```

You can also find the code in form of an example app here: https://github.com/VanCoding/TitaniumNotificationTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set that in your Intent object e.g.:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
    url: 'activity1.js'
});
intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Intent

EDIT:

OK here's a link to a working application using className instead of url: https://github.com/foolprooflabs/AndroidNotificationsCustomActivity

EDIT 2:

Updated Github code, removed unnecessary  tag in tiapp.xml

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already read the docs, but it does not work that way. Also, please note that I can't start the activity manually, the activity gets started automatically when the user clicks on the notification. So your mentioned code does not apply to my situation. Anyways, I've built this one into my sample app, and it does not work at all. You can find the code here: https://github.com/VanCoding/TitaniumNotificationTest/tree/urlTest  The change is in the urlTest branch. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your help! But, sadly, when I click on a notification, the app shows up, but I still get the "HEjjooooooooLLO" window. I don't see the "WOW" window :( I tested it on a Nexus 5 and a Galaxy Nexus. What device are you testing it on? Could you maybe provide an APK so that I can check if it would work when you build it?

Comment: weird....i'm not sure what happened, i've made a new commit and also uploaded the APK I'm testing with.  I'm testing it on GenyMotion simulator "Galaxy S4 with Android 4.2.2 API 17 1080x1920".  Doesn't work for me with TiShadow btw but it does without it.

Comment: phil... I you can't imagine how thankful I am!! Your example works like a charm now. I'm so glad it finally works!! Thank you! =)

Comment: you know...thanks for asking the question, I learned a lot, it's win-win :)

Comment: Hi phil, thanks for the code. I could not manage to it in Alloy. Could you help     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342451/titanium-android-notification-perform-action-when-user-clicks-notification