# Titanium- Open URL when click on notification

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I am stuck to get the click event of notification (android notification area),
actually i want to open web page when user click on the notification.

**here is my code,**

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,
        data : 'http://www.google.com',
        //url : 'http://www.google.com',
        className : 'com.android.browser.BrowserActivity',
        packageName : 'com.android.browser'
    });
    intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    var pending = Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({
        activity : Ti.Android.currentActivity,
        intent : intent,
        type : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY,
        flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
    });
    var dateValue = new Date();
    var notification = Ti.Android.createNotification({
        contentIntent : pending,
        contentTitle : Title,
        contentText : Message,
        tickerText : Title,
        when : dateValue.getTime(),
        icon : Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.appicon,
        flags : Titanium.Android.ACTION_DEFAULT | Titanium.Android.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Titanium.Android.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS,
        sound : Ti.Filesystem.getResRawDirectory() + 'notification.wav',
    });
    Ti.Android.NotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: As far as I can tell your limited to the [Intents available in Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Intent) Although I've never programed for Android, I would guess that you have to use an intent that opens the app with a payload that tells the app to either open a webview or launch the system browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Titanium - Perform Action when user clicks on Android Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266834/titanium-perform-action-when-user-clicks-on-android-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one of @phil worked for me:
https://github.com/foolprooflabs/AndroidNotificationsCustomActivity

But I've switched to gcm.js, because it's much more reliable.
http://iamyellow.net/post/40100981563/gcm-appcelerator-titanium-module

Comment: I too recommend using iamyellow for handling notifications.

Comment: @van-coding I am trying to open a specific window on Notification click. Your first suggestion works but only when app is running in background. If app is not running (removed from background apps tray) then clicking on notification makes the app stuck on splash screen. I see this is handled in gcm.js excellently but can it be used with Local notifications? Do you know a way to fire gcm.js code with Local Notifications? I really need your help.